# Validating answer in textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am constructing a form in Access and I am trying to have a Message Box pop up when the user clicks the command button. I want the box to pop up only if the value the user entered is higher than 25. I have tried some different VBA code but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is 25 a number or text? Where is it entered?

Comment: Would you be able to post some of the code that you have tried to give a better picture for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is the purpose of the message box to allow the user to confirm whether a value > 25 is valid for that specific record?  Or is it to notify the user that a value > 25 is never acceptable?

Comment: The user is entering a number into a textbox and I just want a flag to show up if the data they entered is greater than 25 so they can check and make sure they did not mean to enter a value that high

Comment: Anything over 25 is an accepatble number but is very rare I just want to prevent any inputs that were not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the text box's *Before Update* event to confirm whether its value > 25 is valid.  That means you can catch the invalid values immediately instead of waiting until later (until a command button click event) to do the data validation.

For example, if your text box is named *MyTextBox*, Null is a valid entry, and non-Null values will be numeric ...

```vb
Private Sub MyTextBox_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strPrompt As String

    strPrompt = "The value is > 25.  Is that correct?"
    If Not IsNull(Me.MyTextBox.Value) Then
        If Me.MyTextBox.Value > 25 Then
            Cancel = (MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo) = vbNo)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If the user clicks *No* in the message box, *Cancel* will become *True* which means the update is aborted and the focus remains in that text box.

If the user clicks *Yes* (to confirm the value > 25 is correct in this case), *Cancel* will be *False*, which allows the update to proceed and focus to move to the next control.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you are looking for with something like this:

```vb
Private Sub btnCommand_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    If CInt(Nz(Me.Textbox1.Value, 0) > 25) Then
        MsgBox "Enter Message Here"
    End If

Exit_Handler:
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    If Err.Number = 13 Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a valid number!"
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Sub
```